# How to accsess tsx file from other tsx file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tsx

I'm trying to open my cart page from the *header.tsx* but I'm new with react and I can not figure this out
can you please help me.

I have a place called *cartPopUp.tsx*
that have the logic for openning the cart.

this is the place I want to put `onClick` methods for opening the cart from the *header.tsx* file

```html
<div className="cart">
  <span className={"productCounter"}>{products.length}</span>
  <img src={shoppingCart} alt="" />
</div>
```

this is *cartPopUp.tsx*

```
type CartProps = {
  deviceType: {
    mobile: boolean;
    tablet: boolean;
    desktop: boolean;
  };
};

const CartPopUp: React.FC<CartProps> = ({
  deviceType: { mobile, tablet, desktop },
}) => {
  const { cartState, dispatch, products, totalPrice } = useContext(CartContext);

  const handleModal = () => {
    openModal({
      show: true,
      config: {
        className: 'cartPopup',
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        enableResizing: false,
        disableDragging: true,
        transition: {
          tension: 360,
          friction: 40,
        },
      },
      closeOnClickOutside: true,
      component: CartItem,
      closeComponent: () => <div />,
      componentProps: { onCloseBtnClick: closeModal, scrollbarHeight: 370 },
    });
  };

  const toggleCart = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'TOGGLE',
    });
  };

  let cartSlideclass = cartState.isOpen === true ? 'cartPopupFixed' : '';

  return (
    <>
      {mobile || tablet ? (
        <>
          <CartPopupStyle />
          <CartPopupButton
            className='product-cart'
            itemCount={products.length}
            itemPostfix={
              products.length > 1 ? (
                <FormattedMessage id='cartItems' defaultMessage='items' />
              ) : (
                <FormattedMessage id='cartItem' defaultMessage='item' />
              )
            }
            price={totalPrice}
            pricePrefix='$'
            onClick={handleModal}
          />
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <CartSlidePopup className={cartSlideclass}>
            {cartState.isOpen === true && (
              <CartItem onCloseBtnClick={toggleCart} scrollbarHeight='100vh' />
            )}
          </CartSlidePopup>

          <BoxedCartButton
            className='product-cart'
            itemCount={products.length}
            itemPostfix={
              products.length > 1 ? (
                <FormattedMessage id='cartItems' defaultMessage='items' />
              ) : (
                <FormattedMessage id='cartItem' defaultMessage='item' />
              )
            }
            price={totalPrice}
            pricePrefix={CURRENCY}
            onClick={toggleCart}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default CartPopUp;
```

Comment: Lookup lodash, it's a library with many useful utility functions. groupBy migh be useful, although it given you an object. But you can just call Object.entries() on the result. Or there might be a better function

Comment: Are you referring to `toggleCart` method?

Comment: @MoshFeu yes my friend

Comment: The whole point of shared store (Context in your case) is to let every component to interact with it. So I'd recommend for _header.tsx_ not to consume the method but to call the same action (`TOGGLE`) by itself.